# Efficient NumPy sliding window function

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a function for creating sliding windows from a 1D NumPy array:

```
from math import ceil, floor
import numpy as np

def slide_window(A, win_size, stride, padding = None):
    '''Collects windows that slides over a one-dimensional array.

    If padding is None, the last (rightmost) window is dropped if it
    is incomplete, otherwise it is padded with the padding value.
    '''
    if win_size <= 0:
        raise ValueError('Window size must be positive.')
    if not (0 < stride <= win_size):
        raise ValueError(f'Stride must satisfy 0 < stride <= {win_size}.')
    if not A.base is None:
        raise ValueError('Views cannot be slided over!')

    n_elems = len(A)
    if padding is not None:
        n_windows = ceil(n_elems / stride)
        A = np.pad(A, (0, n_windows * win_size - n_elems),
                   constant_values = padding)
    else:
        n_windows = floor(n_elems / stride)
    shape = n_windows, win_size

    elem_size = A.strides[-1]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        A, shape = shape,
        strides = (elem_size * stride, elem_size),
        writeable = False)
```

(Code has been updated based on Marc's feedback)
Meant to be used like this:

```
>>> slide_window(np.arange(5), 3, 2, -1)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 4, -1, -1]])
```

Is my implementation correct? Can the code be made more readable? In NumPy 1.20 there is a function called sliding_window_view, but my code needs to work with older NumPy versions.

Comment: `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` is written in pure python; if it is not for the sake of a programming exercise, is there any reason why you can't ... faithfully borrow ... their code?

Comment: It doesn't support padding the last element. Maybe that can be added but it looks like lots of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few suggestions:

- **Input validation**: there is no input validation for `win_size` and `padding`. If `win_size` is `-3` the exception says `ValueError: Stride must satisfy 0 < stride <= -3.`. If `padding` is a string, numpy throws an exception.
- **Type hints**: consider adding [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to provide more info to the caller.
- **f-Strings**: depending on the version of Python you use, the exception message can be slightly simplified.

  From:

  ```py
  if not (0 < stride <= win_size):
      fmt = 'Stride must satisfy 0 < stride <= %d.'
      raise ValueError(fmt % win_size)
  ```

  To:

  ```py
  if not 0 < stride <= win_size:
      raise ValueError(f'Stride must satisfy 0 < stride <= {win_size}.')
  ```
- **Duplication**: the statement `shape = n_windows, win_size` seems duplicated and can be simplified.
  From:

  ```py
  if padding is not None:
      n_windows = ceil(n_elems / stride)
      shape = n_windows, win_size
      A = np.pad(A, (0, n_windows * win_size - n_elems),
               constant_values = padding)
  else:
      n_windows = floor(n_elems / stride)
      shape = n_windows, win_size
  ```

  To:

  ```py
  if padding is not None:
      n_windows = ceil(n_elems / stride)
      A = np.pad(A, (0, n_windows * win_size - n_elems),
                     constant_values=padding)
  else:
      n_windows = floor(n_elems / stride)
  shape = n_windows, win_size
  ```
- **Warning**: FYI on the doc of [np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided) there is a warning that says `This function has to be used with extreme care, see notes.`. Not sure if it applies to your use case but consider checking it out.